# HTTP 414 in mule

Tags: apache, mule

Getting below error while sending a HTTP PUT request inside a mule flow.

> CAUSED BY: org.mule.transport.http.HttpResponseException: Request-URI
>   Too Long, code: 414

I think I need to increase allowed header length of Apache server, but not sure about the location, please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For apache server the limit is a configurable value, [LimitRequestLine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestline) . 
Change this value to something larger than its default of 8190 if you want to support a longer request URI.
You can add or update it in [httpd.conf](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/configuring.html) or in one of the `VirtualHost` definitions.

Its recommended not to use above method, instead pass data with body. Please refer [What is the maximum length of a URL](https://boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Anupam, but I am getting this error inside a mule flow, so I need to know how I can do some configuration in a mule standalone server to avoid this error.

Comment: As destination server is returning this error, you cant do much on Mule side.Please check with service provider for uri length or any substitute for URI, like putting data with http body.